# Requested List in SSAS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx

Goal:
My requested result is to apply a new column, named number, containing chronological order with numbers in in a table. I strongly believe that i takes place at DSV designer SSAS.

```
number     Name 
-----------------------
1          water      
2          computer    
3          pencil       
4          bowl          
5          key       
6          candy
```

Problem:
I have difficult to apply the new column, named number, containing chronological order with numbers at DSV designer. I have tried applying a new named calculation with mdx code but I failed.

The question is:

> Is it possible to achieve the requested result it in SSAS
>   multidimensional with mdx only?

The current list in a ROLAP table:

```
Name
---------
computer
bowl
water
pencil
key
candy
```

Information:
Please remember that I do not want to make any changes in the databas or ROLAP. Changes  shall occur at SSAS only, if possible.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Change the order in which the members are displayed when getting the member list and in reports without specific ordering? Change the display order in a specific report? How is the order in the ROLAP table determined? How do you want to determine the new order? Which relational database system do you use? SQL Server? Oracle? Sybase?

Comment: I have revised and please read it again. The table in SSAS will be used in report.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how you get the attribute member sort order different from the default alphabetical one, you do this in dimension designer:

- Create an attribute from the "New number" column.
- Make it related from your attribute named "Name" in the "Relationships" tab.
- Set the "New number" attribute as "OrderByAttribute" of the "Name" attribute, and set "OrderBy" of Name to "AttributeKey".
- Possibly set "AttributeHierarchyVisible" of "New number" to false if it has no specificv meaning to users.

Comment: In this context the sort order is totally new and in order to achieve it you need to apply new data in a column in order to ahcieve a new sort order. It doesn't work to change the orderlist in SSAS. You still use the old sort number and you apply a new sort order. I need to help to apply a new and customized sort order with column "new number". The question is how should I apply the new sort order?

Comment: It is easier to do the work in ROLAP but in this context, it must apply, somehow, in SSAS.

Comment: Do you have the new sort order available as a column in a relational table, or what else is its source?

Comment: The source is located in the rolap table but in this context, it must use SSAS.

Comment: I still do not understand your requirement. Even if it is contained in a relational table, it must be made available to SSAS either as an attribute or as a measure. What is wrong with my proposed solution?

Comment: I can provide you a better explanation by reading this case. 
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819000/new-column-with-numbers)
The case is similar to this case.

Comment: You add the calculated column as described in the solution for the referenced question, then use it like I described here. And that solves the problem.