# New Column with numbers

Tags: ssas, mdx

Goal:
Create a new column, named test , containing numbers in SSAS only inside of DSV design view.

If StatePrinceCode's column has value NSW it shall have value 1 etc.

```
StateProvinceCode    test
------------------------------
NSW                  1
QLD                  2
SA                   3
```

Problem:
How should I enable to do it? I tried using IIF and case statement but it doesn't want to do it due to text value. It only works with numbers only.

Information:
- I strongly believe that you need to create a named calculation as a extra column to add the value

- The new column shall apply in the table Geography in SSAS.
- In this context no usage of SQL server database

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you use in SSAS DSV computed columns is that of the underlying relational database, as actually, this expression is included in the select statement when reading teh data from the relational database. Hence, if you use Oracle as the relational source, it would be Oracle SQL. If you use SQL Server for the relational source data, it would be Transact SQL syntax.

In Transact SQL, you could use a CASE expression (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) as the expression for the `test` calculated column evaluating the `StateProvinceCode` in the `CASE`s.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I strongly interpret that MDX:s disadvantage is to filtrate text value? Is it true? Would it also be same for MDX:s IIF and IF?

Comment: Actually, MDX can do that, but only after it is available in the cube somewhere. And to make it available to the cube, it must be available in the DSV, either as it is already available in the relational source, or defined in the DSV. If you have data in a text file that you load into a relational database table, you cannot work with SQL on the text file. You can only work with SQL on the data after it is loaded into a relational table. The same applies to MDX: Before the data is available in the cube, MDX does not have access to it.